# How to pass a variable in oracle and return the date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

In oracle if we

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate) FROM dual
```

execute this query we will be getting the current date.

But for this I want to pass a variable like say if I pass 2 I want to get the date 2 days back.

If pass 3 I want to get the date 3 days back.

How can i achieve it in oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Upon executing the following script, SQL Developer will ask for value of x.
(Press F5, don't use CTRL+ENTER)

**Query**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
select sysdate - &x from dual;
undefine x;
```

I entered value as 2, it returned the value 28 Jun 2016

**Output**

```
old: select sysdate - &x from dual
new: select sysdate - 2 from dual

SYSDATE-2
---------
28-JUN-16
1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

you cat create function like this

```
create or replace function getDate(p_dNum number:=0) return date is 
begin
  return sysdate - p_dNum;
end;
```

and then call function in your sql like this

```
select to_char(getDate(p_dNum => 2),'yyyy/mm/dd') 
  from dual;
```